# Ruby: require works in gem, fails when running from source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, directory-structure, code-structure

Try creating a gem based on [bundler's official guide on developing a Ruby gem](http://bundler.io/v1.14/guides/creating_gem.html).

Running `bundle gem foodie` will create a structure and generate files in the `lib` directory:

- foodie

  - version.rb
- foodie.rb

foodie.rb reads

```
require "foodie/version"

module Foodie
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

Running `ruby lib/foodie.rb` (or also from different directories) will result in

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- foodie/versio
n (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from foodie.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

On the other hand installing the gem via `rake install` and then requiring the gem  works just fine.

It works from source if `require "foodie/version"` is changed to `require_relative "foodie/version"` in foodie.rb. As I understand

- `require` works based on modules
- `require_relative` works based on directory structure

To me the latter looks like a hack. It'd no longer make sense to structure your code via modules as it wouldn't be enforced (maybe it'd still make sense but you could make mistakes and never notice).

My questions are:

- Is it possible to test a gem from source without installing it while following the bundler convention (using `require` instead of `require_relative`)?
- Why does the gem work after installed?
- Is there any best practice for the usage of `require`, `require_relative`, modules, files and general structure?

Thank you.

Comment: Please break this up into separate questions, because: 1. the three questions you have asked are quite different, and 2. they will be more useful to future readers that way. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I asked it this way because these questions emerged from the same issue/context - I'd imagine others to have similar questions in a similar situation. I think the same context is required for each question. Is it good practice to repeat the same context for several questions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your `lib` dir to Ruby’s *load path*. The load path is a list of directories that Ruby searches for files in when you call `require`. Rubygems also manages the load path when you are using gems, which is why your code works when installed as a gem.

You say “as I understand ... `require` works based on modules”, this is not correct. `require` works with files, it’s just convention that a class or module is defined in a file with a matching name, e.g. `MyModule` might be in `my_module.rb`.

There are a few ways to add a dir to the load path. From the command line you can use the `-I` option:

```
$ ruby -I lib lib/foodie.rb
```

If you wanted to avoid typing `-I lib` you could use the `RUBYLIB` environment variable. Ruby adds the contents of this to the load path:

```
$ export RUBYLIB=lib
$ ruby lib/foodie.rb
```

(On Windows I think you will need to use `set` rather than `export`.)

You can also manipulate the load path from withing the program itself. It is stored in the global variable `$LOAD_PATH`, aliased as `:$`. This is how Rubygems and Bundler manage your gems.

Comment: Thanks! Two remarks / questions: 1, My assumption was that even if you define several modules and classes within a single file you can choose to require only a certain class (e.g. `require A/B/C` with the following structure in a single file: `module A module B class C ... end end end`). Is there no way to achieve this?  2, The takeaway for me is that `require_relative` is the same as `require` except the former has an extended functionality and should therefore be prefered. Do you agree with this or are there any drawback for generally using `require_relative` instead of `require`?